# Этимология "гужевать"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/гужевать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):

> **Этимология**
>
> Происходит от ??

От чего?